# Redirect to log-in page in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm currently working on 2 php pages. a log-in page, and a customer portal page (login.php and portal.php).

My login.php has a FORM `action="portal.php"`. So obviously, when the user's credentials are verified then it will proceed to portal.php page.

However, if the user will type directly the URL for portal.php, the page will display the following:

> Notice: Undefined index: USER in C:\xampp\htdocs\ECMS\portal.php on line 10 Notice: Undefined index: PASS in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ECMS\portal.php on line 10

Is there a way wherein I can automatically redirect the page to login.php, instead of displaying those errors - assuming they didn't logged in yet?

Thank you!

Comment: Please read a book about php first, so you understand what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **portal.php** page , check if request is **POST** or not, like

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'post' ) {
  // do your stuff
}
else{
   // redirect user to login page, if directly hit the page
   header('location:login.php');
}
```

Also you can use the **session** to handle this situation. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Set SESSION on login and check as following on the top of `portal.php`

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user_name'] =="" && $_POST['USER']=='')
{
header("location:index.php");
}
```

Comment: From Kimsoyens question, its clear that the login credentials will be verified on the portal.php (Even though it is a bad decision to do so,) The session will be set only after this verification. So it will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a verification in your `portal.php`. Check if someone is connected using something like `mysqli_num_rows` that counts the number of rows returned. So check if there is no rows returned :

```
    if (mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($db,"Select User from table WHERE Something like '".User."'"))  == 0)
{
 // there is no user connected, so redirect him to the login.php
} else {
 // What to do if the user is connected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of portal.php, authenticate and check if post variable  is set and not empty. If one of the requirement not fullfilled, redirect to login.php page

```
 if($_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] matched with stored username &
 password AND !ISSET AND EMPTY)
 {    
     header("location:login.php");
 }
```

This way, u will achieve two objectives: authentication and redirection.

If you want to keep the username and password across multiple pages, store the POST variable in the SESSION variable. You can read about the SESSION here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp